# how to calculate the date from the year, week-of-year and day-of-week in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

[image]

I have the Year, Week-of-Year and Day-of-the-Week as follows:

```
Year = 2022 (A2) ; Week Year = 35 (B2); Week Day = 4 or Thursday (C2)
```

and I would like to estimate the Date as dd.mm.yyyy, which is highlighted in yellow as it shows in the EXCEL picture.

I tried many formulas, but I am sure there might be an easy one.

Comment: See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables). Can you please [read about when & why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: In Excel there's a difference between the weeknumber (WEEKNUM) and iso weeknumber (ISOWEEKNUM). Which are you calculating with?

Comment: Week number is given from the source data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are counting the weeks starting from zero because for `9/1/2022` (`YYYY/MM/DD` format) the corresponding week is `36` as per the result of function `WEEKNUM(DATE(2022,9,1))`. In order to use the logic to multiply the number of weeks by `7`. You need to use as a reference the first day of the year, if it was a Sunday, if not then go back to the previous Sunday, so you can count the entire week. Bottom line use as a **reference date**, the Sunday of the first week of the year, not the first day of the year (`YYYY/1/1`)

Here is the approach we use in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(y, A2:A6, wk, B2:B6, wDay, C2:C6, fDay, DATE(y,1,1), seq, SEQUENCE(7),
 fDay - IF(WEEKDAY(fDay)=1,0, WEEKDAY(fDay,2)) + 7*wk 
  + XLOOKUP(wDay, TEXT(seq,"dddd"), seq-1))
```

We use the `LET` function to avoid repeating the same calculation. The following expression finds the previous Sunday if the first day of the year (`fDay`) was not a Sunday:

```
fDay - IF(WEEKDAY(fDay)=1,0, WEEKDAY(fDay,2))
```

The `XLOOKUP` function is used to get the numeric representation of the weekday and use the `TEXT` function to generate the weekdays in a long format. Since we count the entire week, if the weekday is a Sunday (column `C` in my screenshot), then we don't need to add any day to our reference date, that is why we use `seq-1`.

Here is the output for several sample data. Assuming the week count starts with zero, if not the formula needs to be adjusted as also the input data.

[image: excel output]

Notice that the year 2021 started on a Friday, so if we want to find a day for the first week (`0`) before Friday it will return a date from the previous year. Like in the case of Monday. If you want an error message instead, then the formula can be modified as follow:

```
=LET(y, A2:A6, wk, B2:B6, wDay, C2:C6, fDay, DATE(y,1,1), seq, SEQUENCE(7),
 result, fDay - IF(WEEKDAY(fDay)=1,0, WEEKDAY(fDay,2)) + 7*wk
  + XLOOKUP(wDay, TEXT(seq,"dddd"), seq-1),
 IF(YEAR(result) <> y, "ERROR: Date from previous year", result))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
Year = 2022 (A2) ; Week Year = 35 (B2); Week Day = 4 or Thursday (C2)

=DATE (A2,1,3)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,3)) + 7 * B2 + C2 - 6
```

Comment: Why C5 ? C5 is blank in your question.

Comment: Chris, check your formula, at least for some cases it doesn't provide the correct result (it returns the previous week). Assuming your week starts on zero. For example for the following input: `2023,1, Friday` returns `1/6/2023`, and for `2023,1, Wednesday` returns `1/4/2023`. Check my response for more details. Maybe I misunderstood your assumptions, that is a possibility too. I am using the following modification of your formula for testing: `=DATE(A2,1,3)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,3))+7*B2+XLOOKUP(C2, TEXT(SEQUENCE(7),"dddd"), SEQUENCE(7)-1)-6`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, but you need to do further testing if it really works.

I calculate month from week: =+MONTH(DATE(YEAR(A2);1;1)+B2*7-1) 
I calculate week day number from week day name: =MATCH(D2;{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"};0)

And then make date using: =DATE(A2;C2;E2)

[image]

Comment: Correct, but I don't have the month. That is the issue